# Solving the Laplace PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I  am reading in Boas M. book, "Methods of Mathematical physics" the following:

Laplace equation:  $\nabla^2T=0$ or $\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial y}=0$.

In this book it is said that with the solution in the form of $T(x,y)=X(x)Y(y):$

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{X}\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial x^2}+\frac{1}{Y}\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial y}=0
\end{equation}

since we differentiate $T$ twice with respect to each variable.

In order to solve it, we assume the two components are equal to some constant, $-k^2$, so we have two ODEs:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
f\frac{1}{X}\frac{\partial^2X}{\partial x^2}=-k^2\\
-\frac{1}{Y}\frac{\partial^2Y}{\partial y}=-k^2
\end{array}
\end{equation}

This is where I cannot understand the result.

I solve each   by the simple quadratic formula :

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2X}{\partial x^2}+k^2X=0 \rightarrow X=\frac{0\pm\sqrt{0-4\cdot k^2}}{2}\rightarrow X=\pm ikx
\end{equation}

This gives inevitably $X=e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}$. Ignoring that there are any constant in front of each term, we get     $X=2\cos kx$. The same is done for Y, and we get

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2Y}{\partial y^2}-k^2Y=0 \rightarrow y=\frac{0\pm\sqrt{0-4\cdot -k^2}}{2}\rightarrow Y=\mp ky
\end{equation}

This gives the same as for X, $Y=e^{kx}+e^{-ky}$.

However, in the book the solutions are

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
fX=\{  \sin kx, \ \ \cos kx \\
Y=\{  e^{ky}, \ \ \ e^{-ky}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

The last two are found, but the sine result does not appear here. How is this found?

Is there something wrong with my approach on using the quadratic formula?

Thanks

**UPDATE**:

$X=Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx}\rightarrow A(cosx+isinx)+B(cosx-isinx)$:

$cosx(A+B)+isinx(A-B)$. Put (A+B)=A and (A-B)=B, set iB=B:

$X= Acosx , X=Bsinx$

Comment: You have $0{\color{red}{+}}4k^2$ in the second ODE giving $\pm k$ not $\pm ik$.

Comment: Yes, I just saw it.

Comment: When you solve the characteristic equation you solve for the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$. And given those eigenvalues you have the general solution being $X = Ae^{\lambda_1 x} + B e^{\lambda_2 x}$. You somehow got $X=2\cos(x)$ which is *a* solution, but not the general one.

Comment: In the book there are no initial conditions so far, they come after. The writer gets both the sine and cosine of kx as a general solution, then later identifies the constant k. But I can't figure out how the writer gets the sine term.

Comment: Since $e^{ikx} = \cos(kx) + i\sin(kx)$ and $e^{-ikx} = \cos(kx) - i\sin(kx)$ and the constants $A,B$ are free you can also write the solution as $X = Ae^{ikx} + B e^{-ikx} =  C\cos(kx) + D\sin(kx)$ (show this).

Comment: OK! I see . Il will update

Comment: You have found a basis for the solution space of ${e^{ikx}, e^{-ikx}}$ and X can be any linear combination of those solutions. Since X must be real, it is better to use an equivalent real basis ${\sin(kx),\cos(kx)}$

Comment: Why must X be real? This is probably where I can't get rid of the i in front of the sine term in the UPDATE.

Comment: X being real will come from the boundary conditions. You might want to tidy up your use of X, Y too, you are using them to equal more than one thing which is a bit confusing.

Comment: Paul, not sure what you mean

Comment: X is a function of x but you have $X=ik$ for example

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume solutions of the form $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ for the Laplace equation $\nabla^2u(x,y)=0$ on a rectangular region $a \le x \le b$, $c \le y \le d$, then you can separate variables by writing
$$
    \frac{\nabla^2 u}{u} = 0 \\
    \frac{X''(x)Y+X(x)Y''(y)}{X(x)Y(y)} = 0 \\       
    \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}.
$$
Assuming you have such a solution $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$, then it follows that the right side cannot depend on $x$, and the left side cannot depend on $y$, which means that neither side can depend on $x$ or on $y$!!! So there must be a constant $\lambda$ such that
$$
         \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=\lambda,\;\; -\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}=\lambda
$$
(Where you put the negative sign is basically irrelevant because $\lambda$ can be positive or negative.) The most general solutions for $X$, $Y$ are
$$        X(x)=A\sinh(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+B\cosh(\sqrt{\lambda}x)\\
Y(y)=C\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}y)+D\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}y)
$$
If you swap $\lambda$ for $-\lambda$, then the solutions may be re-written as the following (with different $A$, $B$, of course):
$$
X(x)=A\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+B\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)\\
Y(y)=C\sinh(\sqrt{\lambda}y)+D\cosh(\sqrt{\lambda}y)
$$
Notice that it is possible to find separated solutions that vanish on 3 of the 4 sides of the rectangular region. And, on the 4th side, you are able to match the value of $u(x,y)$ to an arbitrary function using a Fourier-type expansion. Then you can add 4 solutions to obtain a general $u(x,y)$ that has specified values on all four sides of the rectangular region.

Comment: ! What a great answer, I forgot, and maybe never really dwelled into the properties of hyperbolic sine and cosine, and see now how they give better answer than the exponentials. I will memorize this, because I see that a hyperbolic sine function of time for instance , makes sense, while an exponential form of time, makes no sense at all in nature, unless we are going into a black hole!

Comment: Thanks, and keep in touch DISINTEGRATING BY PARTS! You are a great guy!

Comment: @Luthier : Always good to hear from you.